# Sorted 2D array sorting again on check

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets and trying to confirm, using Google Apps Script, that a range is sorted by the last name (second column).
However, there are duplicates in the second column and, when performing the check, the data is re-sorting before the check, flipping the position of rows where the last name matches, at which point the lists don't match.
For instance, the Sheets range is as follows:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| *Frida* | Acosta |
| *Autumn* | Acosta |
| **Edgar** | Andersen |
| **Kayla** | Andersen |
| Raphael | Andrade |
| Johnathon | Andrews |
| Danielle | Archer |

As you can see, rows {1,2} and {3,4} have the same last name. But I've sorted the data on Last Name from Sheets, so this should be correct. However, when I run the code it resorts and flips them, so that it sorts to:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Autumn | Acosta |
| Frida | Acosta |
| Kayla | Andersen |
| Edgar | Andersen |
| Raphael | Andrade |
| Johnathon | Andrews |
| Danielle | Archer |

and now, obviously, they do not match.

How can I check to see if a 2d array is sorted on a single column without having this happen where it attempts to re-sort the array?

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  let a1 = ss.getRange(4,1,502,5).getValues();
  let a2 = JSON.stringify(a1);
  a1.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a1) == a2);
}
```

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJBbenoiT893yVPFlbYNkqKkyzUtisHc26iRujTpHRo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @marikamitsos why did you remove the "javascript" tag? GAS is Javascript. Also, why didn't my table format correctly?

Comment: If you read the tag descriptions about [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) and [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), you will find that the `javascript` tag is actually in excess. That is why it is not usually applied when `google-apps-script` is in use. Please have [a look]()

Comment: @marikamitsos I just read the full description and don't see anything that obviously tells me it shouldn't be used with GAS, but if that's how it's supposed to be, that's fine. I was kinda just going for the "widest net" approach, since GAS knowledge isn't really necessary for the question.

Comment: I never said that *"it shouldn't be used with GAS"*. Just that *"it is not usually applied..."*. In any case it is not really that important. Call it my mistake :)

Comment: As for *"why didn't my table format correctly?"*. You need to leave an empty line (create a new paragraph) before applying the code syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solutions:**

Basically your approach but without `? 1 : -1`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  let a1 = ss.getRange(4,1,502,5).getValues();
  let a2 = JSON.stringify(a1);
  a1.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] );
  console.log(a1);
}
```

or:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  let a1 = ss.getRange(4,1,502,5).getValues();
  let a2 = JSON.stringify(a1);
  a1.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));
  console.log(a1);
}
```

**References:**

[String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#browser_compatibility)

Comment: The second one works. The first one I had before and it wasn't doing anything, so I added the ? 1 : -1